# core audio user-space plug-in driver - sandbox preventing data interaction from another process

Tags: plugins, core-audio, appstore-sandbox, xpc, mach

I'm working on a coreaudio user-space  hal plugin based on the example
developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Introduction/Intro.html

In the plug-in implementation, I plan to obtain audio data from another process i.e. CFMessagePort

However, I got the following error in console trying to create port CFMessagePortCreateLocal...

**sandboxd[251]: ([2597]) coreaudiod(2597) deny mach-register com.mycompnay.audio**

I did some googlging and came to this article

Technical Q&A QA1811
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1811/_index.html
about adding AudioServerPlugIn_MachServices in plist but still no success.

Is there anything else I need to do to make this work (like adding entitlements, code-sign) or this is not the correct approach.?
I am not sure if MesssagePort mechanism works anymore under sandbox. would XPC Services be viable?

Thank you very much for your time. Any help is greatly appreciated

---

update 1:

I should be creating a remote port instead of a local in the audio plug-in. Having that said, with the AudioServerPlugIn_MachServices attribute in the plist. now there is no **sandboxd[559]: ([552]) coreaudiod(552) deny mach-lookup / register** message in console.

However, in my audio hal plug-in (client side) I have

`CFStringRef port_name = CFSTR("com.mycompany.audio.XPCService");
CFMessagePortRef port = CFMessagePortCreateRemote(kCFAllocatorDefault, port_name);`
 port has return the value of 0. I tried this in a different app and it works just fine.

This is my server side:

```
CFStringRef port_name = CFSTR("com.mycompany.audio.XPCService");
CFMessagePortRef  port = CFMessagePortCreateLocal(kCFAllocatorDefault, port_name, &callback, NULL, NULL);
CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource =
CFMessagePortCreateRunLoopSource(nil, port, 0);

CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                   runLoopSource,
                   kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
CFRunLoopRun();
```

I did get a console message regarding this.

**com.apple.audio.DriverHelper[1314]: The plug-in named SimpleAudioPlugIn.driver requires extending the sandbox for the mach service named com.mycompnay.audio.XPCService**

anyone know why??

---

**update 2**

I noticed that when I use the debug mode with coreaudiod it does successful get the object reference of the mach service. (same thing happened when I was trying the xpc_service approach)
[project scheme setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMs21.png)

Anyone??

Comment: Hi Allen, just trying to setup debugging this. First of all, how did you manage to debug using coreaudiod at all ? I get "error: attach failed: lost connection" all the time...

Comment: @Robert I got my info here:  [Debugging a user-space HAL plugin?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreaudio-api/PDQ3V5NrGI0)  and [Debugging an AudioServer plugin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreaudio-api/g5TrSW4hJFw)

Comment: Thanks @Allen, I finally got it to work by setting "csrutil disable" in Recovery OS mode, so that debugging coreaudiod got possible! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016558/how-should-finder-sync-extension-and-main-app-communicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I was running into the same problems in my AudioServerPlugIn. I could look up and use every Mach service I tried, except for the ones I had created. And the ones I had created worked normally from a regular process.

Eventually I read [the Daemonomicon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION10) and figured out that `coreaudiod` (which hosts the HAL plugins) was using the global bootstrap namespace, but my service was being registered in the per-user bootstrap namespace. And since *"processes using the global namespace can only see services in the global namespace"* my plugin couldn't see my service.

You can use `launchctl` to test this by having it run the program that registers your service, but with the same bootstrap namespace as `coreaudiod`. You'll probably need to have rootless disabled.

```
# launchctl bsexec $(pgrep coreaudiod) your_service_executable
```

With that running, try to connect from your plugin again.

From Table 2 in the Daemonomicon, you can see that only launchd daemons use the global bootstrap namespace. That explains why `coreaudiod` uses it. And I think it means that your Mach service needs to be created by a launchd daemon.

To make one, create a [launchd.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) for your service in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. Set its owner to `root:wheel` and make it only writable by the owner. In it, set the `MachServices` key and add the name of your service:

```
<key>MachServices</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.mycompany.audio.XPCService</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Then register it:

```
# launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycompany.audio.XPCService.plist
```

This is what I ended up with: [com.bearisdriving.BGM.XPCHelper.plist.template](https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic/blob/f3151e31594885487a36a9d18c2a53f3d85c2696/BGMApp/BGMXPCHelper/com.bearisdriving.BGM.XPCHelper.plist.template). Note that without the `UserName`/`GroupName` keys your daemon will run as root. (The code for [my service](https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic/tree/f3151e31594885487a36a9d18c2a53f3d85c2696/BGMApp/BGMXPCHelper) and [plugin](https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic/blob/690d6221d7cf2880d73928653d8bb76fb4730bf7/BGMDriver/BGMDriver/BGM_XPCHelper.m) is in that repo as well, in case that's helpful.)

I ended up having to use XPC, unfortunately, but I tried CFMessagePort first and it worked fine.

It also seems to all work fine whether the plugin is signed or not. Though, as you say, you do need the `AudioServerPlugIn_MachServices` key in your Info.plist.

Comment: Thank you @freshtop for replying in a very descriptive way. I was able to make the XPC communicate in a slightly different approach than the one you suggested here (not sure if it's the appropriate way).  I created my C-based xpc functions in a  **int main(int argc, const char * argv[])** intermediary process. Did sudo chown root with my plist in /LaunchDaemons.  I'm going to spend some time going over your example. Really appreciate your answer. by the way, that CFMessagePort never worked for me. would've been great if it did.

Comment: I still can't seem to get this working (a year later). I've combed over Background Music and this answer several times and I'm still seeing the dreaded `requires extending the sandbox for the mach service` error and no connection. Permissions seem right, ownership seems right, launchd is verified to be working on the XPC service and it's bootstrapped using `launchctl bootstrap system /System/LaunchDaemons/my.service.plist` to no avil. :| I'm at wits end.

Comment: Why did to end up having to use XPC instead of CFMessagePort?

Comment: @RuurdAdema Not sure, sorry. I actually reread this answer recently and asked myself the same question. The main thing I'm using XPC for is to block in StartIO until another process tells my plug-in it can start IO, so my guess is that I wasn't able to receive the reply from the CFMessagePort until after I let StartIO return. That said, just from the docs, I don't see why I wouldn't have been able to receive the reply on a different thread.

Comment: CFMessagePort won't work with Catalina, I'm struggling on getting XPC working